# Irreducible elements are not associates

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I would like to know if every irreducible elements in a ring are not associates. I'm asking that because of this part in the page 61 of this [book](http://books.google.com.br/books/about/Steps_in_Commutative_Algebra.html?id=Oi4x9NznFEUC&redir_esc=y):
[image]

Thanks a lot

Comment: In the quoted passage the author doesn't rely on any two (distinct) irreducible elements being "not associates", but instead on our ability to collect (irreducible) factors that are associates into one term $p_i^{t_i}$ by appropriately combining the unit factors which relate them as associates.

Comment: @hardmath: Hitting the nail on the head with that one. Make it an answer?

Comment: @CameronBuie: Thanks!  I peg it as a Comment (and upvoted Noah's succinct Answer) because I addressed subtext, not the Question the OP literally asked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two primes are associates if one of them is a unit times the other.  For example, in the integers $5$ and $-5$ are associates (as are $p$ and $-p$).  More trivially a prime is always an associate of itself.

You should think of "not associates" as a slightly stronger version of "distinct."